# How to check if an xml node contains text with XmlStreamreader?

Tags: java, xml-parsing

Suppose my XML looks like this

```
<books><genres><crime><book>ABC</book></crime></genres></books>
```

I don't know which tag will have text value inside beforehand. I want to check if a node has text contained in it and then store it.

I am using the code like this:

```
XMLInputFactory inputfacory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
XMLStreamReader reader = inputfacory
        .createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader(
                "path"));
while (reader.hasNext()) {
    if (reader.next() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
       System.out.println(reader.getLocalName());
        if(reader.next()==XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS){
            //store string
        }
    }
```

output is:

```
books
crime
```

But the problem is, in that case, the reader is going to by pass the genres and the book tags as `reader.next()` is taking it to the next event. Any way to check if a node has text content without using `reader.next()`?

Comment: Do you want to store the node or the text itself ? and do you want to store in a list ?

Comment: Do u found any solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

You could `isCharacters()` method like below :

```
try
{
    String input = "<books><genres><crime><book>ABC</book></crime></genres></books>";

    XMLInputFactory inputfacory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
    XMLStreamReader reader = inputfacory
                    .createXMLStreamReader(new  StringReader(input));

    List<String> texts = new ArrayList<String>();

    while ( reader.hasNext() )
    {
        reader.next();
        if ( reader.isCharacters() )
        {
             texts.add( reader.getText() );
        }

    }

    for ( String text : texts )
    {
        System.out.println( text );
    }
}
catch ( Exception ex )
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This i had checked.But i need to know the node name inside which the text is stored as well.That is why i am checking if the reader is a start element,checking if the next event is characters.But then the reader is already moving on to the next event which may be a child node.Then this child node will not be processed as part of my check at the beginning of the loop if (reader.next() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT)